# Navigation Drawer Item Title Color

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been searching around trying to fix this problem but I can't seem to find the answer. I have multiple items in this navigation drawer and each one of those items holds a menu of other items. The parent items have a title associated with them and I want to change the text color but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I would really appreciate the help, and here is an image to more accurately understand my issue.

[Navigation Drawer: Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZZ8z.png)

Thank you for the help in advance!

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Yes please add your xml.

Comment: XML has been added

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `NavigationView` introduced in material design library then add following attribute to change the color of your drawer item

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/my_ripple"    //sets background of the item
    app:itemIconTint="@color/item_icon_color"      //sets color of the drawer item icon
    app:itemTextColor="@color/item_color"     //sets color of the drawer item
    ....
 />
```

Comment: I do have these in my xml and this doesn't exactly fix my issue. The problem is the item Title color that I need to change.

Answer (score -1):

you put navigationview like that.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorContentBG">
        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />
        <ListView
            android:entries="@array/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listMenu"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

and whatever ui design for listview.

Comment: If you are already setting header as `app:headerLayout` in NavigationView then you don't need to include that layout as it's child.

Comment: This is closer but not exactly what I am looking for. I would really just like to change that text color in the image above, but thanks for your suggestion!